# Use australia-southeast1 region in skaffold.yaml google cloud kurbernetes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, skaffold

I'm trying to use dockers on my local machine (macos) with google cloud kubernetes. I have setup the skaffold.yaml file as below in the project and like to push the image to a storage service in australia-southeast1 and not us.gcr.io

How do i specify the image to australia-southeast1?

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  googleCloudBuild:
    projectId:  ticketing
  artifacts:
    - image: us.gcr.io/
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use a regional support, in this case `australia-southeast1` you would have to choose to use the Artifact Registry as it only supports region support as per [this document](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr#compare), but it looks like by Skaffold's default it's a Container Registry so as per the [this document](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr#compare) it looks like you should probably choose `asia.gcr.io` as the closest multi-region for Australia is Asia.

Comment: Just a note that Skaffold does support Artifact Registry: just specify the image as `australia-southeast1-docker.pkg.dev/ticketing/image/name` where `image/name` is @Jag99's desired image name.